# VB.net - Serializing a class that has events

Tags: vb.net, serialization, data-binding

Sigh...
I have a class that has properties that have events. The event is fired when a property has changed in value. The instance of the class is a backer for the information on a form. I need to save the information that is in the form for later recall.

The idea here is to bind the properties as datasources to the textboxes and datagridview on the form. That is the driver for the event to update the textbox or datagridview when the value of the class changes.

So...when I use the following code to save a file of a static variable (test) it works fine:

```
Dim test As String = "Hello"
    ' Persist to file
Dim save As New SaveFileDialog
If save.ShowDialog = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK Then
    Dim stream As FileStream = File.Create(save.FileName)
    Dim formatter As New BinaryFormatter()
    formatter.Serialize(stream, test)
    stream.Close()
End If
```

If I try it using the instance of the class that backs the data it is throwing errors because of the class has events:

```
Dim test As new ClassWithEvents()
    ' Persist to file
Dim save As New SaveFileDialog
If save.ShowDialog = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK Then
    Dim stream As FileStream = File.Create(save.FileName)
    Dim formatter As New BinaryFormatter()
    formatter.Serialize(stream, test)
    stream.Close()
End If
```

The error:

> Type 'System.Windows.Forms.Form' in Assembly 'System.Windows.Forms, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' is not marked as serializable.

All I really want to do is keep the values of the controls on a form for later recall.

Any ideas?

Comment: what are the errors?  The events themselves should not be an issue because it is the props that are serialized.  is it the firing of events tied to props being set?

Comment: Error was added above in the post.

Comment: What is Test?  Is it a Form?  Forms arent serializable (nor are Controls...at least not directly).

Comment: Test is the variable that I am serializing. IN the first case it is a simple string. In the second case it is a custom class - not a form.

Comment: The error indicates NET thinks it is a form.  Hard to tell what is going on without seeing some of the class.  At the least you have a property which is a Form Reference.

Comment: It seems that the custom class has members of types that are not marked with a Serializable-attribute. If so, consider exchanging those types by other custom types which can store the same information...

Comment: Seperate the state (model) that is consumed by the class in question (view, viewmodel, etc). Have a constructor on that class that takes the model. So all you really need to do is then serialize and deserialize the model as needed.

Comment: See this article   [link]http://www.lhotka.net/WeBlog/CommentView.aspx?guid=776f44e8-aaec-4845-b649-e0d840e6de2c It discusses a solution. Unfortunately, the solution did not work for me. I still had the same error.

Answer (score 1):

The likely failure mode here is that your class has an event that was subscribed.  And the target of the event handler was a method that's part of a Form class.  Yes, that cannot work, the Form class is not serializable.  Nor would you *want* to serialize the event, it is pretty unlikely to deserialize properly.

You suppress serialization of a member of a class by applying the `<NonSerialized>` attribute on the member.  Unfortunately that's pretty hard to do in VB.NET, it does not work on a member declared with the Event keyword.  VB.NET events are rather special.  The workaround is to use a Custom Event instead, one that use a private backing field which you can prevent from getting serialized.  That looks like this:

```
<Serializable()> _
Class ClassWithEvents
    <NonSerialized()> _
    Private Events As New System.ComponentModel.EventHandlerList

    Public Custom Event Foo As EventHandler
        AddHandler(ByVal value As EventHandler)
            Events.AddHandler("foo", value)
        End AddHandler

        RemoveHandler(ByVal value As EventHandler)
            Events.RemoveHandler("foo", value)
        End RemoveHandler

        RaiseEvent(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)
            CType(Events("foo"), EventHandler).Invoke(sender, e)
        End RaiseEvent
    End Event

    '' etc..
End Class
```

You'll have to do that for every event in the class.  You can re-use the Events variable, just change "foo" to "bar".  Not a lot of fun of course.  Do consider a dedicated class that only has the properties you want to serialize as an alternative.

Comment: Hans...Wow! Thanks for the detailed explanation and example! That works quite well. Thanks again.

Comment: Hans: I am having an issue. When the object gets deserialized it cycles through the AddHandler and RemoveHandler in the custom event. When it cycles through the AddHandler it throws an exception "Object reference not set to an instance of an object". I do not have experience with custom events. I am quite confused by this. I did mark Events as nonserialized:     <NonSerialized()> _
    Private Events As New System.ComponentModel.EventHandlerList

Answer (score 0):

Since you have said that "All I really want to do is keep the values of the controls on a form for later recall", some possible methods would be to:

1. loop recursively through all the controls (and sub-controls) on the form and store the relevant properties in a serializable data structure.
2. Bind your controls to an in-memory database, and serialize your data from that.